# Swift array and dictionary performance, removeAll() vs new instance

Tags: ios, swift

I have an array (or dictionary) and need to clear it. Performance wise, is it better to `removeAll()` or create a new instance?

```
var things = [Thing]()

// Need to clear things
things.removeAll()
// or
things = [Thing]()
```

Comment: These two alternatives don't do the same thing.

Comment: In short;  doesn't matter.   It is unlikely that the performance difference of doing either is going to be measurable.   And, until you measure a difference that actually impacts app performance, then it is a premature optimization anyway.   As well, either path is effectively going to have to do a removeAll() to release the objects that may be contained, anyway.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

(I accidentally misread your question and looked it up for `Dictionary`, see below for `Array`)

## Dictionary

`thing = [String : Thing]()` vs. `thing.removeAll()`

Now that Swift is open-source, we can have a look at whether those two statements actually do something different.

### New initialisation

After digging through the source I found the initialiser for a `Dictionary` [here](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/a78567a26954f0b2093097db038b07e970b7c4e5/stdlib/public/core/HashedCollections.swift.gyb#L960-L970):

```
public init() {
  self = Dictionary<Key, Value>(minimumCapacity: 0)
}

/// Create a dictionary with at least the given number of
/// elements worth of storage.  The actual capacity will be the
/// smallest power of 2 that's >= `minimumCapacity`.
public init(minimumCapacity: Int) {
  _variantStorage =
    .Native(_NativeStorage.Owner(minimumCapacity: minimumCapacity))
}
```

As you can see, the underlying storage, which is the only property, gets assigned on initialisation.

### removeAll

Now let's have a look at `removeAll()` from [here](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/a78567a26954f0b2093097db038b07e970b7c4e5/stdlib/public/core/HashedCollections.swift.gyb#L3415-L3440):

```
  internal mutating func removeAll(keepCapacity keepCapacity: Bool) {
    if count == 0 {
      return
    }

    if !keepCapacity {
      self = .Native(NativeStorage.Owner(minimumCapacity: 2))
      return
    }

    if _fastPath(guaranteedNative) {
      nativeRemoveAll()
      return
    }

    switch self {
    case .Native:
      nativeRemoveAll()
    case .Cocoa(let cocoaStorage):
#if _runtime(_ObjC)
      self = .Native(NativeStorage.Owner(minimumCapacity: cocoaStorage.count))
#else
      _sanityCheckFailure("internal error: unexpected cocoa ${Self}")
#endif
    }
  }
```

Here you can see that the condition `!keepCapacity` will be true, because `removeAll()` is just `removeAll(keepCapacity:)` with a default argument of `false`. This code is from the storage enum, so it replaces itself with a new empty storage with a minimum capacity of 2.

### Conclusion

Both statements do pretty much the same in theory, but I can imagine that in practice the initialisation can get optimised away, so that they do **exactly the same**.

## Array

`things = [Thing]()` vs `things.removeAll()`

### New initialisation

For array it's even easier to see [here](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/a78567a26954f0b2093097db038b07e970b7c4e5/stdlib/public/core/Arrays.swift.gyb#L497-L499):

```
public init() {
  _buffer = _Buffer()
}
```

### removeAll

See [here](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/a78567a26954f0b2093097db038b07e970b7c4e5/stdlib/public/core/Arrays.swift.gyb#L747-L754):

```
public mutating func removeAll(keepCapacity keepCapacity: Bool = false) {
  if !keepCapacity {
    _buffer = _Buffer()
  }
  else {
    self.replaceRange(self.indices, with: EmptyCollection())
  }
}
```

As with the dictionary, `_buffer` is the only property of `Array`.

### Conclusion

Same as for `Dictionary`: Both statements do pretty much the same in theory, but I can imagine that in practice the initialisation can get optimised away, so that they do **exactly the same**.

Comment: Very nice complete answer, with source code to back it up

Comment: Can someone explain why the documentation of the `removeAll()` method says `Complexity: O(n), where n is the number of key-value pairs in the dictionary.`? In this case it sounds like initialising a new dictionary/array should be faster.

Comment: It shows the worst case. Best case is when keepCapacity is false and it's O(1) but if keepCapacity is true it's O(n)